# In Bash, how to extract a word and a following number from a file?

Tags: bash, sed, awk, text-extraction

I've got a list which has many entries of two different formats:

```
Generated Request {some text} easy level group X
---or---
easy level group X {some text}
```

where X is a number between 1-6 digits long.

I'm trying to go through that file line by line and reduce down everything to just "group X" on each line (so that I can then compare it to another file).

I'll post my attempt below so you can join me in laughing at it, but I'm just picking up the basics of bash, awk and sed, so I apologize now for this assault on good scripting...

```
for line in $(< abc.txt);do
  if [ ${line:0:2} == "Ge" ] then
  awk '{print $8,$9}' $line >> allgood.txt
  elif [ ${line:0:2} == "ea" ] then
  awk '{print $3,$4}' $line >> allgood.txt
  fi
done
```

The attempted logic was, if it starts with "Ge", then extract phrases $8 and $9 and append to a file. If it starts with "ea", then extract phrases $3 and $4 and append to the same file. However, this doesn't work at all.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach for this problem is to use `grep`:

```
grep -o 'group [0-9]*' file
```

The `-o` option displays only the matching part of the line.

---

You never have to use `bash` to loop over every line in a file then pass the line to `awk` as this is exactly how `awk` works, it iterates over each line and applies the relevant blocks. Here is an approach using your logic in pure `awk`:

```
awk '/^Ge/{print $8,$9}/^ea/{print $3,$4}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with "while read" and avoid awk if you prefer:

```
while read a b c d e f g h i; do 
  if [ ${a:0:2} == "Ge" ]; then 
    echo $h $i >> allgood.txt; 
  elif [ ${a:0:2} == "ea" ]; then
    echo $c $d >> allgood.txt;
  fi;
done < abc.txt
```

The letters represent each column, so you'll need as many as you have columns.  After that you just output the letters you need.

Comment: This is a useless use of `cat` it should be replace with `done < abc.txt`.